# How to set a formula in a JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a PreparedStatement that I use to insert a bunch of rows with a lot of column data. However, for one of the columns (a Timestamp), if the value is null, I want it to execute `getDate()` on the server.

I understand that I could just do `new Date()` but that's not really going to work, because, due to legacy reports, it needs to match exactly another column that has the value automatically inserted.

Let's also say I can't change the schema and add a default value to the column.

Is there any way I can set a formula as a parameter in the PreparedStatement?

Edit to Add:
Here's essentially what it is currently:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into row (name, starttime) values (?, ?)")
statement.setString(1, name);
statement.setDate(2, date);
```

What I want is, something like:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into row (name, starttime) values (?, ?)")
statement.setString(1, name);
if(date != null)
  statement.setDate(2, date);
else
  statement.setFormula(2, "getdate()");
```

I understand that:

```
if(date == null)
  date = new Date();
```

is essentially the same thing, but in our case, it's really not.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I am confused as to the actual question at hand. What kind of formula are you mentioning, and what good would it do as part of the preparedStatement?

Comment: @Peaches491 edited for better info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it work to simply prepare a statement of the form

```
insert into row(name, starttime)
   values(?, coalesce(?, getdate())
```

? and then setting a null 2nd parameter should cause a getdate() call?

Comment: @reverend-gonzo  @araqnid  I used your logic `conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TableA (colA) VALUES(IFNULL(?, 1))")` but this is failing with exception `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in operation`  Could you please suggest Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The only option I can think of, since you cannot change the schema, is to have 2 prepared statements, one with the default getdate() in the query, the other that takes a parameter.  Then you can simply do something like:

```
PreparedStatement ps = (date == null) ? prepareWithDefault : prepareWithoutDefault;

// Set all variables //

if (date != null) {
  ps.setDate(date);
}

ps.execute();
```

Comment: Yep ... I think this really is the only way around this .... which sucks since i've had the sql abstracted out